# How I can make svg icons appear after spring-boot:run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, webpack

I'm trying to place som icons from sprite.svg file

That's the fragment of my component in react, where I want to place image.
and webpack config. I placed sprite.svg in href, but it doesn't works. Am I need to change my webpack.config, or install some modules?

```
<div className="product__actions">
    <div className="rating">
        <svg width="20px" height="20px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <use xlinkHref="#icon-rating"/>
        </svg>
        <span className="rating__result">{this.props.product.money_value}</span>
    </div>
 </div>
```

that's my webpack config

```html
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: './src/main/js/home/home.js',
        products: './src/main/js/products/products.js',
        ....
        _catalog: './src/main/resources/styles/_catalog.scss',
        ....

    },
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            ...
            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
                include: [path.join(__dirname, "src/assets")],
                loader: "file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]"
            }
            ...
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: './src/main/resources/static/css/[name].css'
        }),
        new MergeIntoSingleFilePlugin({
            files: {
                "./src/main/resources/static/styles/styles.css": [
                    './src/main/resources/static/css/_catalog.css',
                    .....
                ]
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

How I can solve this problem, pls help!

Comment: You are missing a closing div tag on your html. Is that just a typo or is that how you have it in your code?

Comment: It looks like the `xlink` attribute is deprecated. The documentation is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href. Try just using `href`

Comment: Also, because you are camel casing `xlinkHref` react is probably treating it like a prop rather than a built in attribute.

Comment: Thx for your response, tried to place href, div tag was just a typo, yes. Unfortunately nothing changes

Comment: it seems svg page doesn't see svg file import

Comment: Where is the `#icon-rating` element located?

Comment: Sorry, didn't response at time, I fixed it. I placed wrong path: 

<use href="./resources/static/sprite.svg#icon-rating"/>

That solved my problem, is that correct solution?

Comment: Thx a lot, for your response, by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use correct full path to sprite.svg file

```
<use href="./resources/static/sprite.svg#icon-rating"/>
```

It works for me